# Why is this happening (strangeness with Processing and UnfoldingMaps)

Tags: java, processing, unfoldingmap

As part of the coursera UCSD Java class, we are working with the Processing and Unfolding Maps libraries.

The course provides you with starter code, which I am trying to expand. But I ran into a problem.

On my work computer, where I do most of my studying, I have a really nice app started. I decided to take it home to my wife to show her, by cloning my github repo to my home laptop.

None of the librar/JAR files were included, so I downloaded them directly from Processing and Unfolding's download pages. The result was a NIGHTMARE. Error after error after error. I assume coursera/UCSD used old versions of the libraries, and the new versions aren't backwards compatible. Seems crappy, but whatever.

Next, I downloaded all the JAR files from the coursera sight. The results are a bit better, but things are still pretty wacky. Namely, when I create an `UnfoldingMap()` object, the parameters for location within the window as well as size do absolutely nothing.

1.) I use Processing `size()` method to size up or down the containing window, it scales the map object up or down. It totally ignores the size and location arguments of `UnfoldingMap()`.

2.) The map object is always pushed to the lower left hand corner of the window, no matter it's arguments for position.

3.) The gray `background()` I have chosen does show around the map, but the background itself is then surrounded by a big black field, that also scales with the `size()` parameters.

Here is some code:

```
package module3;

//Java utilities libraries
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

//Processing library
import processing.core.PApplet;

//Unfolding libraries
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.marker.Marker;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.data.PointFeature;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.marker.SimplePointMarker;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.MBTilesMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;

//Parsing library
import parsing.ParseFeed;

public class EarthquakeCityMap extends PApplet {

    // Less than this threshold is a light earthquake
    public static final float THRESHOLD_MODERATE = 5;
    // Less than this threshold is a minor earthquake
    public static final float THRESHOLD_LIGHT = 4;

    // This is where to find the local tiles, for working without an
        // Internet connection 
    public static String mbTilesString = "blankLight-1-3.mbtiles";

    // The map
    private UnfoldingMap map;

    //feed with magnitude 2.5+ Earthquakes
    private String earthquakesURLweek = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.atom";
        private String earthquakesURLday = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.atom";

    public void setup() {
            size(400, 400, "processing.opengl.PGraphics3D");
            background(99);

            map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 1100, 700, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());
        map.zoomToLevel(2);
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);   

        //List of markers to be added to map
        List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

        //Use parser to collect properties for each earthquake
        //PointFeatures have a getLocation method
        List<PointFeature> earthquakes = ParseFeed.parseEarthquake(this, earthquakesURLweek);

            // for each earthqauke feature, create a custom marker and add it
            // to the list.
            for (PointFeature quake : earthquakes){
                Marker quakeMark = createMarker(quake);
                markers.add(quakeMark);
                Map<String, Object> properties = quakeMark.getProperties();
            }

        // Add the markers to the map so that they are displayed
        map.addMarkers(markers);
    }

        /**
         * A helper method to style markers based on features (magnitude, depth,
         * etc) of an earthquake.
         * @param feature A PointFeature object representing a single earthquake.
         * @return 
         */
    private SimplePointMarker createMarker(PointFeature feature){  

            // Create a new SimplePointMarker at the location given by the PointFeature
            SimplePointMarker marker = new SimplePointMarker(feature.getLocation(), feature.getProperties());

            Object magObj = feature.getProperty("magnitude");
            Object ageObj =  marker.getProperty("days ellapsed");
            float mag = Float.parseFloat(magObj.toString());
            int age = (int) ageObj;

            //Set processing color and alpha data, for setting marker colors 
            //below.
            int alpha = 255 - (age * 255 / 7);
        int yellow = color(255, 255, 0, alpha);
            int red = color(255, 0, 0, alpha);
            int green = color(0, 255, 0, alpha);

            // Style markers based on earthquake magnitude
            if (mag < THRESHOLD_LIGHT){
                marker.setColor(green);
            }
            if (mag >= THRESHOLD_LIGHT && mag < THRESHOLD_MODERATE){
                marker.setColor(yellow);
            }
            if (mag >= THRESHOLD_MODERATE){
                marker.setColor(red);
            }

            //set radius of marker based on quake magnitude
            float radius = (float) (mag * 3.5);
            marker.setStrokeColor(color(50,15));
            marker.setRadius(radius);

        return marker;
    }

    public void draw() {
        map.draw();
        addKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option would be use an outdated version Processing that Unfolding still supports like [Unfolding 0.9.6 (for Processing 2.2.1)](https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/releases).

Since you're using eclipse you can actually compile a newer version might work for you.
(I'm noticing there are a few [minor updates](https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding/commits/master) from last year, but no release).
To update via eclipse you can:

1. get the repo (if you're on a Unix system (Linux/OSX) you might already have `git` installed: `git clone https://github.com/tillnagel/unfolding` : this way you can always pull the latest updates and rebuild easily, otherwise download zip, unzip, etc.)
2. import the project in eclipse (via Import Existing Project)
3. Drag build.xml from the project into the [Ant View](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-85a_ant_view.htm) and select a target to compile. `main` will compile all of them including the Processing wrapper.

If you want to use command line only:

1. Install [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) (if that's not already on your system) and add it to your `PATH` environment variable (e.g. to check `echo $PATH` on Unix or `echo %PATH%` on Windows and ensure the folder where ant lives is listed, if not added it)
2. clone/download the repo
3. run ant (e.g. `ant unfolding_processing` to build the Processing wrapper only or simply `ant` (which defaults to the `main` target building everything)

I can confirm manually compiling the latest version from github works with Processing 3.4
[image: centre of earthquakes in Romania]

I've uploaded the Processing wrapper [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/Unfolding.zip): Hopefully you can drag the .jar file on top of your eclipse project.

Comment: Hi there. First, thank you. Second, is there a rough equivalent of what you suggest using NetBeans? That is my IDE of choice. 

Also, am I to understand that either Processing or Unfolding Maps are outdated in some way? If so, which one? The course I'm signed up for is very old, so I'm not surprised. Finally, what is Ant? When I start a new project on NetBeans, the default is "Java with Ant", but I've never concerned myself with what that means before...

Possibly too many questions for a comment. Sorry.

Comment: A pleasure :) I haven't used NetBeans in ages, but it's a solid Java IDE. Processing libraries tend to use eclipse, however you can import the Unfolding [eclipse project into Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/import-eclipse.html). Ant is [a build system](https://ant.apache.org/): eases tasks like compilation, doc. generation, running, etc. I see there's an detailed [NetBeans Ant tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-ant.html), however you simply need to learn how to run ant (as build.xml is already there). Unfolding Maps' latest release is outdated at the moment.

Comment: What would be a take-away from this situation, as a new "programmer", trying to pull code from an online repository? I'm thinking it would be something along the lines of knowing the dependencies of the project, as well as the version of those dependencies?

Comment: In an ideal world everything should've just worked: Processing is great for new programmers, the Processing wrapper for Unfolding should simplify the more verbose draw java code, easy right ? :) Unfortunately if libraries/code/docs aren't up to date you find yourselves jumping through hoops. The take-away can be cynical/positive depending how you look at it. Not many things "just work", a lot are broken, a lot don't age well and break with time so expect things to be worse before they get better. You learn a lot more when things go wrong (things you would otherwise not even touch).